# Why mutual exclusion is required in MapReduce distributed system?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, sharing, distributed-system, mutual-exclusion

I am new to distributed systems.
I want to know about Mapreduce distributed programing model. That why do we need mutual exclusion in Mapreduce? 
How mutual exclusion is solved in Mapreduce?

Comment: Question quality needs to improve, need to add more details to it, what exactly you are trying and what is expected?

Comment: You need to be more attentive during class. Too easy bro, just refer janib sir's tutorials on YouTube. You won't find it anywhere else. copyright ni hai Kisi ko  :) :) :)